# Do you have to roll to cast a spell in D&D 5E?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, attack-roll

So me and my friends are playing D&D 5E and my friend wants to cast magic missiles. Our DM says that he has to roll to cast the spell but my friend says he does not. So according to the rules of D&D 5E do you have to roll to cast magic missiles or any other spells? Do you need to roll for each missile to hit?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Spells do exactly what they say they do.  Magic Missile doesn't require roll.  Some spells require attack rolls, others require the target to roll a saving throw -- but those are spelled out in the description of the spell.  Magic Missile automatically hits.

Here it is from Jeremy Crawford's mouth: http://www.sageadvice.eu/2015/10/11/is-magic-missile-an-attack-that-hits-without-an-attack-roll/